Vanishing of tensor products, incorrect argument about $xm=0$ implys $m\in Ann(x)M$.
(Equational Criterion for Vanishing). - Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ and $N$ modules, and $\left\{n_\lambda\right\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ a set of generators of $N$. Then any $t \in M \otimes N$ can be written as a finite sum $t=\sum m_\lambda \otimes n_\lambda$ with $m_\lambda \in M$. Further, $t=0$ if and only if there are $m_\sigma \in M$ and $x_{\lambda \sigma} \in R$ for $\sigma \in \Sigma$ for some $\Sigma$ such that
$\sum_\sigma x_{\lambda \sigma} m_\sigma=m_\lambda$ for all $\lambda$ and $\sum_\lambda x_{\lambda \sigma} n_\lambda=0$ for all $\sigma$.
My question is that since $R\otimes_R M=M$. If $xm=0$, then $x\otimes m=0$. $m=\sum_i r_im_i$. $r_ix=0$, $m\in $Ann$_R(x)M$, which should not be true generally unless $M$ is flat.
